# Where does user-uploaded content go in my AWS S3 storage?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've set up my AWS S3 storage for my Django project. My `static` folder in my S3 Bucket has all my static files. However where do the files which would usually go in `media` go? i.e files uploaded from users?

Comment: Refer this  [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use a /Media root in my AWS bucket and I set the file upload directories to go there

in settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'yourapp.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

In another file lets say storage_backend.py, I defined the following

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

and Finally this is the data type in my models.py

```
to_upload = models.FileField()
```